# Can I Write It As An Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, pi

Is there a way to write $$\Pi _{i=1}^n (i)$$ as an integral?

[ $\because \Pi (x) = \Gamma (x+1) $ and $\Gamma (x+1) $can be written in form of an integral , that's why i am asking, can we write above equation also? If yes, how?]

Comment: $\Pi _{i=1}^n (i)=n! = \int_0^1 n! dx.$

Comment: There are infinitely many integrals that evaluate to $n!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$P_n=\prod_{i=1}^ni=n!=\Gamma(n+1)$$
and since for $x > 0$
$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$
we also can say that
$$\prod_{i=1}^n i=\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}dt$$

Comment: Hey, in last step , pls correct it by putting (i) in front of Pi symbol....else, thanks. It helped me!!